# Pyreverse UML with complex type hints (Union, List, ...)

Tags: python, uml, pylint, class-diagram, pyreverse

I am trying to generate a UML diagram for a class that uses Unions and List typehints.

An example of it would be

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union   

@dataclass
class ClassA:
    name: str    

@dataclass
class ClassB:
    an_attribute: int    

@dataclass
class ClassC:
    my_class: Union[ClassA, ClassB]
```

When running `pyreverse -ASmn stackoverflow_example.py -o png` I obtain an UML not showing usages of classA and classB:

[image: UML class diagram with three unconnected classes A,B and C]

If I replace the code in `ClassC` to

```
@dataclass
class ClassC:
    my_class: ClassA
```

Then I get an UML description closer to my goal:
[image: UML class diagram, with 3 classes A,B and C, C being composed with A]

But of course, this means that when I assign something of type `ClassB` to `my_class` I get a warning highlighted, which is exactly what it should do.
My understanding of how the `Union` should work is that I would get something like this:
[image: UML class diagram manually edited, with 3 classes A,B and C, C being composed with A and with B]

The example shows Union, but List and others will have similar behaviours.

Is there a way of doing this, or is this a design that shouldn't be done?

Comment: I would not put much trust in any such tools except getting a rough overview (which might be helpful in many cases). It's probably that they just inspect the header and do not dive into the guts of code (which declarations are). Btw. the _closer to goal_ uses a label for a connector which does not reflect the code.

Answer (score 6):

### How should it be in UML?

According to [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) that specifies type hinting:

> A type factored by Union[T1, T2, ...] is a supertype of all types T1, T2, etc., so that a value that is a member of one of these types is acceptable for an argument annotated by Union[T1, T2, ...].

But in UML, this would require an intermediary type,  because there can be only one `my_class` member:

[image]

### How to get it in pyreverse?

Looking at the different options of pyreverse,  there is not much we can do:

- You may add the option `-b` for including built-in types.  In this case, you'll see that all the classes inherit from `object`, and you'll see `int` and `str`  including composition of members of that type.  But `Union` stays desperately as it is, and it does not show anything like PEP 484 suggest. This suggest that this feature is not supported by pyreverse.
- Pyreverse shows exactly the same behavior for Union, as if you'd add a type that does not exist (e.g. `xxxx` or even nonsense such as `xxx [1,2,yyy]`): it indicates the string as it is in the source file but doesn't draw the corresponding objects.  This reinforces the impression of lack of support.
- In a last experience,  I processed the example file with the typing.py package together in pyreverse.  It identified nicely the dependency between packages.  But still no change for union.
- Using the alternative syntax `ClassA | ClassB` leads to a slightly different diagram, as type information is completely removed but not composition is shown either.

I can only conclude that the graphical rendering of unions does not seem supported by this tool.

### Workaround for unions?

The Union is a practical feature but that is not very object oriented:

- UML has [no direct support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59554837/3723423) for it, and you’d need to deal with it as explained above.
- Union group together potentially unrelated types, and this does not facilitate polymorphic programming.

Fortunately there is an easy replacement: make A and B subclass of a common empty class, say AB, and make `my_class` an `AB`. Pyreverse then generates the expected result:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this is currently not supported by `pyreverse`. The creation of additional intermediary diagram nodes from type annotations like Union or Optional is not in the scope of this tool.

Comment: @dudenr33 Thank you very much for this very useful confirmation. May I kindly ask if you are part of the pylint contributor team or if you have another source?

Comment: Not only part of the team, but also responsible for more than 60% of the modifications done to pyreverse in the last 10 years (the plantuml implementation in particular) https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3ADudeNr33+is%3Aclosed+label%3Atopic-pyreverse ;)

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Wow ! Impressive ! I feel very honoured for your feedback :)

Comment: Thanks Christophe, I wasn't aware this would go against UML. 
It's interesting that what seemed to me to be a goal of the tool is not supported, as *not* having the arrows is confusing, and having both clearly highlights the intent of the developer. @dudenr33, do you know if there's a possibility to get these arrows even without the intermediary type, or is pyreverse aiming at strict UML, and therefore this would break with its philosophy?

Comment: @Droopi the Union is a feature that is not very object oriented: UML has no direct support for it, and you’d need to deal with it with an intermediary type.   There is an easy replacement: make A and B subclass of a common class AB and make my_class an AB. This should give you a very similar diagram to the one I have drawn.  I guess it’ll not be easy to start adding intermediary types in the existing tool. But perhaps something could be done for the List, since this should just add an association with multiplicity * on the side of the target type?

Comment: Thanks for the update regarding making a "classAB", which is true, I did think of something like that, but I couldn't quite figure out how to make my architecture work, not without compromises. For what it matters here, both A and B are already inherited from another ClassD, but typehinting with the D loses the value of the typehinting in code (eg auto-completion). The code having clear priority over whatever diagram I can or cannot automatically get out of it... So maybe this is less of a UML question and more of a "How can I automatically make a nice drawing of this stuff I've already done".

Comment: @Drooppi there is currently no way I am aware of for displaying just two composition arrows from the type hint alone. This is because, as you already noticed, complex type hints are not well supported yet. `pyreverse` does not aim for strict UML, as long as the intent of the diagram is clear. For multiplicity associations there is actually a open pull request at the moment: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/6434 
I have opened a feature request on GitHub for the remaining cases, but I can't promise when this will be implemented: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/6737