# Pyreverse dont take relationship when I type data like List[class]

Tags: python, uml, pylint, pyreverse

Hello I have the following clas

```
class Page(BaseModel):
    index_page:int
    content:str

class Book(BaseModel):
    name:str
    pages: List[Page] = []
```

The problem is that when I execute pyreverse it isn't set the relationship between Book and Page

But if I change the class Book to

```
class Book(BaseModel):
    name:str
    pages: Page
```

Pyreverse take and draw that relationship

I can imagine that the problem is List typing, but don't know how can I resolve this

Is there anyway of do it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyreverse UML with complex type hints (Union, List, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388388/pyreverse-uml-with-complex-type-hints-union-list) - it's more general but also covers lists, and the author of perverse confirmed in an comment to the selected answer that this feature is currently not implemented by pyreverse.